# Crystal reports -> Handling multiple database connections?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, database-connection

Which is the correct procedure to set login information on multiple database connections/sources within a `Crystal` reports document?

Currently I use the method `SetDatabaseLogon()` on the report. Is it possible call this many times before executing a report (to set different connections)?

Or should I skip `SetDatabaseLogon` and instead set `LogonInfo` on each table?

Comment: I'm new to working with CR inside of Visual Studio, but I'm under the impression you need to set the specific logon information for each table used in the report.